# Having ESP32 synchronized time for blinking LED using NTP sever

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, ntp

I would like to blink the ESP32 onboard LED (pin 2) every 5 seconds.  I have set up a program that sets the time fro NTP sever.  After loading the same code onto 3 different ESP32s, the LEDs blink every 5 seconds but are not at the same time. Is this a hardware issue or is my code incorrect? (also, is there a easier way to do this?). Thank you in advance!

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>

// Wifi Credentials
const char* ssid       = "OhanaAhimsa";
const char* password   = "Fam2021Wow!";

//NTP Sever initalization
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
const long  gmtOffset_sec = 3600;
const int   daylightOffset_sec = 3600;

// start now time variable in seconds
//int time_now = now();
//int second ();

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);

// Connect to WiFi
  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" CONNECTED");
  
  //init and get the time
 configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);

  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return;
  }

  //disconnect WiFi as it's no longer needed
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
}
  
void loop() {

 // if (now() > time_now) {

    // Reset the time_now to now
  //  time_now = now();
    
    // print out seconds:
  // Serial.println(time_now);
   Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
    // Sets the LED on or off depending on time_now being pair or odd
    digitalWrite(2, second() % 5);
  }

void printLocalTime(){
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
  Serial.print("Day of week: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%A");
  Serial.print("Month: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%B");
  Serial.print("Day of Month: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%d");
  Serial.print("Year: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%Y");
  Serial.print("Hour: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%H");
  Serial.print("Hour (12 hour format): ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%I");
  Serial.print("Minute: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%M");
  Serial.print("Second: ");
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%S");

  Serial.println("Time variables");
  char timeHour[3];
  strftime(timeHour,3, "%H", &timeinfo);
  Serial.println(timeHour);
  char timeWeekDay[10];
  strftime(timeWeekDay,10, "%A", &timeinfo);
  Serial.println(timeWeekDay);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't wait until time is retrieved from the NTP server and you don't set the time into the TimeLib.

add

```
  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  while (now < SECS_YR_2000) { // wait until time is retrieved
    delay(100);
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  setTime(now); // sets the time in TimeLib
```

With `setSyncProvider` and `setSyncInterval` you can setup for TimeLib to sync with ESP32 RTC (which is set from NTP) periodically. See the examples of the TimeLib.